# Gauss' Lemma Proof Clarification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am trying to follow a proof of Gauss' lemma in [*Number Theory* by George Andrews](https://archive.org/stream/NumberTheory_862/Andrews-NumberTheory#page/n127/mode/2up). I have a few problems with a couple assumptions made.
Let g.c.d.$(m,p)=1$ where $p$ is an odd prime, and let $\mu$ be the number of integers in $$\lbrace m,2m,..., \frac12(p-1)m \rbrace$$
whose least residues modulo $p$ are negative. The notation for the least residue of $m$ modulo $p$ is $LR_p(m)$. The first problem I have is when it is stated that for any $n$, since $0 \lt |LR_p(nm)| \lt p/2$ as $n$ takes all integral values in $(0,p/2)$, so does $|LR_p(nm)|$. **Why is this so?** I don't see why the least residue would behave like this.

Besides that, I can follow the proof to where it is stated $$ \left(\frac mp\right) \equiv(-1)^\mu \pmod p$$
where $\left(\frac mp\right)$ is the Legendre symbol. 
Following that, it is stated that the congruence implies $$\left(\frac mp\right)=(-1)^\mu$$ which is where I fail to see the connection. I know each side of the congruence will equal either $1$ or $-1$, but **how is it that $\mu$ is necessarily even if $m$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ ($\left(\frac mp\right)=1$) and necessarily odd otherwise?** Apparently these are supposed to be obvious, so I would appreciate any help in understanding them.

---

Edit:
Of the two questions I have figured out the former, but not the latter.

Comment: for anyone interested, all relevant text available at https://books.google.com/books?id=NV68AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=Gauss%27+lemma+in+Number+Theory+by+George+Andrews&source=bl&ots=YCwEeICGju&sig=6wS2apDpjTFTXNxaVXbVRPp1bYU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMI_u_Mic_oxgIVSE-ICh1EFwDC#v=onepage&q=Gauss%27%20lemma%20in%20Number%20Theory%20by%20George%20Andrews&f=false

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for linking, I also included a link to the text at archive.org in the question.

Comment: Anyway, my suggestion is to do examples of all the calculations that might be involved with small numbers. Most people do not fully appreciate a theorem by going through just once, examples that work, examples that initially appear to violate the theorem are all important. For beginning number theory, that means calculations with all symbols replaced by specific numbers, see what happens and why, several different examples until it begins to make sense and seem inevitable.

Comment: by the way, the number of elements in that set IS $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$, so $\mu=\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$. check out this textbook around page 95. there is a proof of quadratic reciprocity theorem which is similar proof but with a lattice diagram that may help. http://people.whitman.edu/~gordon/higher_math.pdf

Comment: @ElliotG $\mu$ is the number of elements whose least residue modulo $p$ are negative. Thanks for the reference, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you may know the answer to your first question already, I give it here for other people. The list of positive integers

$|LR_p(m)|$, $|LR_p(2m)|$, ... $|LR_p(\frac{p-1}{2}m)|$

does not contain any repeated value, because when $|LR_p(n_1m)|$ = $|LR_p(n_2m)|$, then either $n_1m \equiv n_2m$, hence ( remember that gcd(m,p)=1) $n_1 \equiv n_2$, or $n_1m \equiv -n_2m$, hence $n_1 \equiv -n_2$, both of which cannot be the case for two different values in the range of $n_j$ values used in the list. So $n_1 = n_2$.

Then, summarizing the proof in Andrews' book, when the product of $m$, $2m$, ..., $\frac{p-1}{2}m$ is taken, this clearly equals $(\frac{p-1}{2})!\cdot m^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

And when the product of $LR_p(nm)$ is taken for n ranging from 1 to $\frac{p-1}{2}$, this is clearly equal to the product of the signs of these least residue values, times the product of their absolute values - and we just saw that taking the product of their absolute values is congruent (mod p) to taking the product of the numbers 1 to $\frac{p-1}{2}$, which is again equal to $(\frac{p-1}{2})!$.

Striking out left and right the factor $(\frac{p-1}{2})!$ (allowed as this value is not a multiple of p), leaves us with the result that

$m^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (-1)^\mu$.

Now combine this with the fact that $(\frac{m}{p}) \equiv m^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$, and we get

$(\frac{m}{p}) \equiv (-1)^\mu$

In your second question you overlooked a very simple thing: the numbers left and right in the above congruence equation can only take values 1 or -1, so (p is odd) they must be equal in value. So we get the desired result:

$(\frac{m}{p}) = (-1)^\mu$